# Asp.Net Core Custom IdentityUser for existing DB schema

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity-3

I have inherited an existing database (with data) and I would like to use Identity 3.0 and its features. I can not change the schema of the database. From what I've researched it seems doable, but I would need to override a lot of things.

My question is, what exactly do I need to override in to be able to use the schema below? UserStores, RoleStores, UserManager etc. Also how do I map the user schema to IdentityUser (`Id` mapped to `UserId`, `PasswordHash` mapped to `Password`)?

Here's what the DB schema looks like:

[image]

A few things to note, `UserId` column name instead `Id`, and there's a specific hashing algorithm I need to implement on the password for a user to be authenticated.

An example of how to implement this would be appreciated very much.